# How to create multi-project structure in Intellij IDEA like Visual Studio

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am basically from windows development background and used visual studio very much. Recently, I am asked to worked on Java and I find Intellij IDEA community edition. I have one question, like how can I create multiple project in one solution? where we just build the top level solution and all sub-project builds automatically?

Any idea or tutorial in this case would be really helpful.

Answer (score 6):

You can add multiple Maven or Gradle projects to your IntelliJ-Projects by using the plus-button in the Maven/Gradle Projects toolbar. 
This opens a file browser that allows you to choose an additional .pom/.gradle file to add a project.

Afterwards you can create Build-Actions that build both projects at the same time using Maven or Gradle. Or you build everything using the IntelliJ build (Menu -> Build -> Make Project).

[image]

Having said that, kardans solution works just as well and should always be preferred if you want to build all projects using the command line or continuous integration.

Comment: Thanks for help. I will see if I can do it.

Comment: I moved away from that project for time being. I will try your suggestion when I will be back on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create empty maven project. Next you can add  maven modules to main project. Each one module you can treat as Project in Visual Studio and main Maven module as Solution. On build main project, all modules will be build.

Comment: Thanks for help. I will see if I can do it.